# WTF form.validate_on_submit() not working

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have the following code and I'm submitting a form. When I hit the submit button, my form validation prints out `False`. I've checked and made sure I'm including everything from different posts, but I can't get it to validate. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

```
@app.route('/index.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def index():   
            user = {'nickname': 'Rafa'}
            form = FilterForm()
            print("about to validate", file=sys.stderr)
            if form.validate_on_submit():
                    print("validated", file=sys.stderr)
                    filters_array = form.filter.split(',')
                    streaming(filters_array)
                    response = {"response", "yes"}
                    redirect("/authenticate")



            return render_template('index.html',
                    title="Home",
                    user=user,
                    form=form)

    class FilterForm(Form):
            filter = StringField('filter', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Here is my Jinja file

```
    {% block content %}    
      <h1> I have successfully navigated to the title pagee </h1> 
      <h1> Hello, {{user.nickname}}!</h1> 
      <h1> Get Tweets </h1> 
      <p> Please enter a comma delimited list of filters</p>   
      <form action="" method="post" name="login"> 
        {{form.filter(size=80)}} 
      <input type="submit" value="Get Tweets!"> 
      </form> 
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`FilterForm` should not be indented at the same level as `def index()`. More importantly, you don't have a `csrf_token` in your form. Which will prevent it from validating.

Add this to your form:

```
{{ form.csrf_token }}
```

Lastly, when validating with wtforms, the errors are populated in the form object. So after an `if validate`, try printing `form.errors` and you'll find out exactly what is wrong.

Comment: I have my csrf token as a part of a config file that I have. Is that enough?

Comment: See: https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#creating-forms . Again, print `form.errors`. Each form needs a `csrf_token`.

Comment: I solved this by adding {{ form.hidden_tag() }} under my form tag.

Comment: I was trying to make requests from Postman and getting .validate_on_submit() it False. Do you know a way to avoid getting False?

Comment: @ShivKrishnaJaiswal This answer is in regard to an HTML form that contains a CSRF token. Postman as far as I know cannot be used for testing forms that use CSRF tokens. In fact CSRF tokens protect an application against exactly that.

Comment: The perfect question for a perfect answer.  I was almost smashing my head against the wall. This answer reminded me of a common-sense solution. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Another requirement is that when you use `form.validate_on_submit`, you have to make sure that you had use all fields of your form model.

Comment: Thanks man! This was my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have found some syntax error in your code, maybe that will cause the problem you have met.

first, the problem in your decorator **app.route**:

```
app.route('/index')
```

second, in your html file:

```
form action='/index'
```

Answer (score 0):

its not related to this exact question, but if you face issue like this and errors show nothing, you have `{{ form.csrf_token }}` or `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}`, ypu printed all data in form, and it looks ok that means it is in hundred procent a typo in form html somewhere.

Try rewrite form using templates:
in `_formhelpers.html`:

```html
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <dt>{{ field.label }}
  <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul class=errors>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  </dd>
{% endmacro %}
```

usage:

```html
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<form method=post>
  <dl>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ render_field(form.username) }}
    {{ render_field(form.email) }}
    {{ render_field(form.password) }}
    {{ render_field(form.confirm) }}
    {{ render_field(form.accept_tos) }}
  </dl>
  <p>{{ form.submit }}
</form>
```

it's much easier to avoid typos and other mistakes.

source:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/wtforms/#forms-in-templates

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I simply put `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}` in html Jinja template, nested in the form tag. Now, it's working perfectly.

Here are the versions of some Flask-related packages i have installed here:

- Flask==3.0.1
- Flask-WTF==1.2.1
- Jinja2==3.1.3
- Werkzeug==3.0.1
- WTForms==3.1.2