# Flask WT-Form not getting Validated

Tags: python, flask, server, flask-wtforms

My Flask form is not getting validated. Tried everything. form.validate() is not validating, although, there is no validation present. Is there any way out of this situation?

HTML Code

```
<body>
    <form method="POST" action = "{{ url_for('/generate') }}" novalidate>
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }} <br>
        {{ form.IsAssistantComm() }} <br>
        {{ form.Submit() }} <br>
    </form>
</body>
```

Flask Code

```
class GeneratorForm(FlaskForm):
    To = StringField('TO')
    IsAssistantComm = BooleanField('Is Assistant Commissioner?')
    Submit = SubmitField('Generate')

@app.route('/generate', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def generate():
    form = GeneratorForm()
    if form.is_submitted():
        print("submitted")
    if form.validate():
        print("valid")
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print("I am here")
        IsAssistantComm = form.IsAssistantComm.data
        return redirect('/')
    return render_template('main.html', form=form)
```

Program Stacktrace:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5090/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
submitted
127.0.0.1 - - [30/May/2020 18:48:08] "POST /generate HTTP/1.1" 200 -
submitted
127.0.0.1 - - [30/May/2020 18:48:09] "POST /generate HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `print(form.errors)`, it would help with debugging.

Comment: Also, I don't think you need both `{{ form.csrf_token }}` and `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}` in your template file, hidden tag should include the CSRF token.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WTF form.validate\_on\_submit() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36440003/wtf-form-validate-on-submit-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken here, but I think it just might be the fact that you have no form validation in your GenerateForm class, do something like this :

```
class GeneratorForm(FlaskForm):
To = StringField('TO')
IsAssistantComm = BooleanField('Is Assistant Commissioner?', validators =[DataRequired()])
Submit = SubmitField('Generate')
```

Let me know if that fixes it :D